# How to get the next element of a knockoutjs observable array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js, observable

I need to implement 2 buttons (next, previous) for array elements of an observable array. Is there any default function or any way to navigate between elements of the array?

Ex:

```
var mainArray = ko.observableArray([{id:1,name:'one'},{id:2,name:'two'}]);
```

When I click the next button, it should return the next object (like ko.utils.arrayFirst() returns the given object)

Any help?

Comment: Have an observable that holds an index into the array. Next increments it, prev decrements it. You can wrap around or just hold steady at the ends of the array. If you're doing a match like `ko.utils.arrayFirst` does and you want next and prev to find matches, it gets trickier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, there is no "default" way to do this.

RoyJ's comment is spot on about how to do it yourself. Let me turn it into a working example:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.mainArray = ko.observableArray([{id:1,name:'one'},{id:2,name:'two'}]);
  
  var _currentItemIndex = ko.observable(0);
  
  function navigate(nrOfSpots) {
    if (_currentItemIndex() + nrOfSpots >= self.mainArray().length) { return; }
    if (_currentItemIndex() + nrOfSpots < 0) { return; }
    _currentItemIndex(_currentItemIndex() + nrOfSpots);
  }
  
  self.next = function() { navigate(1); };
  self.prev = function() { navigate(-1); };
  
  self.currentItem = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.mainArray()[_currentItemIndex()];
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

Current Item: 
<i data-bind="text: currentItem().name"></i>
<br />
<button data-bind="click: prev">Previous</button>
<button data-bind="click: next">Next</button>
```

It utilizes:

- A private variable with an observable indicating the current index;
- Two functions `prev` and `next` to change that index (for sofar valid/possible);
- A computed to return the current item at that index.

The view (html) is just for demo purposes.